# BlockChain for Storing personal Data

Tags: blockchain, storing-data

I want to store Personel data to BlockChain for a company. We want to prove that the data is unchangeable. A Customer in the blockchain will not access or see any other customer data.

But Company will access all customer data and can make any operation and also can follow any operation, any access Log.

Company will store new form type(Personal data) and flag it as a personal data card.

Is it possible with Blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be to encrypt the data, but it really depends upon what you are doing with it. If you need to do operations on it, then you will have to use zk-SNARKs, but these are a new field and you would have to do a lot of research to get it working. If you aren't using the data for anything; it's just metadata, then why would you need it to be on a public ledger and validated?

Plus, there is one big problem about storing sensitive data on the blockchain: the blockchain is immutable and once something is on the blockchain, it is stored *forever*. So what if there comes a time when quantum computers become so powerful that they can break all encryption we have today? Then all your users' personal data will be public on the blockchain.